# App freezes my whole phone, just by clicking on launch icon

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, appdelegate

I am a new developer, and I am currently making my first app. 
Sometimes when I try to open the app, the icon dims, but nothing happens, and the whole phone briefly becomes unresponsive. My guess is this is happening in app delegate. I'm not sure what is happening, but I think I should be using grand central dispatch.

this is currently my code in app delegate,

```html
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
//Facebook SharedInstance            FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
//Firebase Database
        FIRApp.configure()
        FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true

//Onesignal PushNotifications
        _ = OneSignal(launchOptions: launchOptions, appId: "3b2b4845-0b6a-4e92-892f-254c2cf51da8", handleNotification: nil)
        _ = OneSignal(launchOptions: launchOptions, appId: "3b2b4845-0b6a-4e92-892f-254c2cf51da8", handleNotification: { (message, additionalData, isActive) in
            NSLog("OneSignal Notification opened:\nMessage: %@", message)
            
            if additionalData != nil {
                NSLog("additionalData: %@", additionalData)
                // Check for and read any custom values you added to the notification
                // This done with the "Additonal Data" section the dashbaord.
                // OR setting the 'data' field on our REST API.
                if let customKey = additionalData["customKey"] as! String? {
                    NSLog("customKey: %@", customKey)
                }
            }
            }, autoRegister: true)
        print("didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions")
        return true
    }
    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        print("application")
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }
```

Is it possible, that this has nothing to do with app delegate?

if it is in app delegate how can use GCD to make this work

Comment: What does `FIRApp.configure()` do? Or is one of Firebase's own methods?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and step through the code one line at a time.  See which line causes the problem.  Alternatively, when the app freezes, click on the pause button to get into the debugger and look at what's happening on the main thread.

Comment: Thank you, I will try setting the breakpoints,

Comment: FIRApp.configure() initializes firebase into our app

Comment: I like Phillip's comment, but an alternative to that could be to remove/comment all the code from your app delegate methods and see if the problem still exists.  If it goes away, then try restoring a little bit at a time until you see the problem come back.

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
import FirebaseMessaging
```

and

```
FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
```

from the AppDeleget and try running it